# Outputing Strings in oop without system.out.println

Tags: java, oop, methods

im trying to output my details from my object class in a method and i remember using a method similar to this

```
 String output;
     output = "Name: " + this.Name;
     output = "Address: " + this.Address;
     output = "Balance: " + this.balance;
     output = "Minutes used" + this.minutes;
     output = "Texts Sent: " + this.texts;
     output = "Cost per Minute: " + this.unitMinuteCost;
     output = "Cost per Text: " + this.unitTextCost;


     return output;
```

i think we were using some kind of string-builder how do i output all these when i return output

Comment: Most IDEs can generate this method for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start be concatenating the `String` values, for example...

```
 String output;
 output = "Name: " + this.Name;
 output += "Address: " + this.Address;
 output += "Balance: " + this.balance;
 output += "Minutes used" + this.minutes;
 output += "Texts Sent: " + this.texts;
 output += "Cost per Minute: " + this.unitMinuteCost;
 output += "Cost per Text: " + this.unitTextCost;
```

Or you could use `StringBuilder` for the same task

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(128);
output.append("Name: ").append(this.Name);
output.append("Address: ").append(this.Address);
output.append("Balance: ").append(this.balance);
output.append("Minutes used").append(this.minutes);
output.append("Texts Sent: ").append(this.texts);
output.append("Cost per Minute: ").append(this.unitMinuteCost);
output.append("Cost per Text: ").append(this.unitTextCost);

return output.toString();
```

But the compiler will do this for you automatically.  If you were creating the output within a loop, it would be advisable then to use a `StringBuilder` as the compiler would not be able to make this kind of optimisation itself

Comment: Ouch, a StringBuilder appending the results of more StringBuilders.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yep, my bad, copy-n-paste

Comment: +1 not pretty, but faster.  BTW the first example would be faster/shorter if you replaced `;\n output +=` with `+` but I see you are trying to match the question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It would my preferred approach as well

Comment: Could some please explain the reason for downvote? In what way does this not answer the ops question?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use `StringBuilder`? ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html))

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
output.append("Name: ").append(this.Name);
output.append("Address: ").append(this.Address);
```

etc...